# "minOccurs" and generated type in Java Contract-First web service

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I've got problem with contract-first generated web service in Java. In my schema I've got something like this:

```
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="GUID" type="xs:long" />
```

Which generates class with field like this:

```
protected long GUID;
```

Now, when I try to fire my webservice, when don't put any value for GUID, the default value of new java long is set (0) and no exception is thrown. Of course this is not good behaviour because I the guid element should be required. 
On the other hand, when I change my schema element to something like this:

```
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GUID" type="xs:long" />
```

(Which is from logic point of view incorrect because GUID element is required) generated class field looks like this:

```
{protected Long GUID; }
```

And now when no GUID is set in web service execution, GUID value is null, which I can check I throw exception from java code.

So I would like to kindly ask you for advice how to using minOccurs="0" generated class with protected Long GUID; (or at least getting exception when this value is not being set)

I'm using JAXB provided with glassfish 2.1.1 and SopaUI for executing web services.

Comment: I was able to find solution. Very simple: I had to add nillable="true" :

<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="GUID" type="xs:long" nillable="true" /> 

And type of filed in generated class is Long now!

BTW. This shows that describing your problems is good even if no one answer to it (maybe it's simmilar mechanism like in "Rubber duck debugging" method? :) )

Comment: Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find solution. Very simple: I had to add nillable="true" :

```
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="GUID" type="xs:long" nillable="true" />
```

And type of filed in generated class is Long now! 
BTW. This shows that describing your problems is good even if no one answer to it (maybe it's simmilar mechanism like in "Rubber duck debugging" method? :) )